# Is knowing the class of probability density function mandatory for explicit density estimation?

Tags: density-estimation

In deep learning, models may learn the probability distribution that generated the dataset. Observe the following paragraph from [Chapter 5: Machine Learning Basics](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) from the book titled [Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) (by Aaron Courville et al.)

> Unsupervised learning algorithms experience a dataset containing many
> features, then learn useful properties of the structure of this
> dataset. **In the context of deep learning, we usually want to learn the
> entire probability distribution that generated a dataset, whether
> explicitly, as in density estimation**, or implicitly, for tasks like
> synthesis or denoising. Some other unsupervised learning algorithms
> perform other roles, like clustering, which consists of dividing the
> dataset into clusters of similar examples.

I read about density estimation in the same chapter, as given below

> In the density estimation problem, the machine learning algorithm is
> asked to learn a function $p_{model} : R^n \rightarrow R$, where
> $p_{model}$(x) **can be interpreted as a probability density function
> (if $x$ is continuous)** or a probability mass function (if $x$ is
> discrete) on the space that the examples were drawn from.

This question is focused on explicit probability density estimation in continuous case i.e., learning density function $p_{model}$  directly.

Suppose I have a dataset $D$ with $n$ continuous random variables (features) $X_1, X_2, X_3,\cdots, X_n$. And I don't know anything about the probability density function of individual random variables. That is, I don't know about any information about any $X_i$ , such as, whether $X_i$ follows normal distribution or any other distribution. Then, is it possible to learn density function explicitly? Or do I need to provide some necessary information such as the class of probability distribution function to be learned?

I am thinking as follows:

If I have some information about $X_i$, such as: $X_i$ falls to a well known distribution, then I can learn the parameters of the underlying density function from $D$. So, is it mandatory to know some information about the underlying probability density function.

Answer (score 0):

[Neural Networks can approximate any function](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-neural-nets-can-approximate-any-function-a878768502f0). Quoting the essence in case the article is removed in the future.

> The key to neural networks’ ability to approximate any function is that they incorporate non-linearity into their architecture. Each layer is associated with an activation function that applies a non-linear transformation to the output of that layer.

So no, knowing the class of the probability density function is not required to approximate it via Deep Learning. With a large enough number of samples you could construct an approximation.